# How can I specify HYDRATE_ARRAY in the table convenience methods?

Tags: doctrine, doctrine-orm, dql

With Doctrine 2, is there any way to specify `HYDRATE_ARRAY` when I use the convenience methods `EntityRepository::find` or `EntityRepository::findOneById`? Do I have to write my own DQL query, and use that instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, but I think you can't.

You will have to write your own DQL, or fetch an object and later serialize it to an array.

Second approach is probably slower, but it comes handy for testing environment. I have used *beberleis* serialization class found [here](https://gist.github.com/1034079#file_serializable_entity.php).

It works ok, except you can't serialize *one-to-many* and *many-to-many* relations in an object, in other words anything that should serialize as an collection of objects.

Btw. if you don't have *php5.4*, just replace the `trait` with an `abstract class`, and have all your model object inherit from that class